# HTTP POST request with authorization on android

Tags: java, android, http, authorization, request

When I set "Authorization" header with setHeader from HttpPost then hostname disappears from request and there is always error 400 (bad request) returned. Same code is working fine on pure java (without android) and when I remove setting "Authorization" header also on android it works fine, but I need authorization.
This is a code (domain changed):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myhost.com/test.php");
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)");
post.setHeader("Host", "myhost.com");
post.setHeader("Authorization",getB64Auth());
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[body]", "test"));
AbstractHttpEntity ent=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
ent.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
ent.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
post.setEntity(ent);
post.setURI(new URI("http://myhost.com/test.php"));
HttpResponse response =client.execute(post);
```

Method getB64Auth() returns "login:password" encoded using Base64 like: "YnxpcYRlc3RwMTulHGhlSGs=" but it's not important.

This is a piece of lighttpd's error.log when above code is invoked on pure java:

```
2011-02-23 15:37:36: (request.c.304) fd: 8 request-len: 308
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)
Host: myhost.com
Authorization: Basic YnxpcYRlc3RwMTulHGhlSGs=
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

and record from access.log (IP changed):

```
1.1.1.1 myhost.com - [23/Feb/2011:15:37:36 +0100] "POST /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)"
```

When the same code is invoked on android, I get this in logs:

```
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)
Host: myhost.com
Authorization: Basic YnxpcYRlc3RwMTulHGhlSGs=

Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Connection: Keep-Alive
Expect: 100-Continue


2011-02-23 15:45:10: (response.c.128) Response-Header:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 349
Connection: close
```

access.log:

```
1.1.1.1 - - [23/Feb/2011:15:45:10 +0100] "POST /test.php HTTP/1.1" 400 349 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)"
```

How to get Authorization with POST working on android?
When I use HttpURLConnection instead of HttpClient it is no difference.

Comment: is there an extra line between Authorization and Content Length Header?

Comment: Yes, there is an extra line but only when request is sent from android.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Thanks to Samuh for a hint :)
There was an extra newline character inserted which has no means in GET requests, but matters in POST ones.
This is proper way to generate Authorization header in android (in getB64Auth in this case):

```
 private String getB64Auth (String login, String pass) {
   String source=login+":"+pass;
   String ret="Basic "+Base64.encodeToString(source.getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
   return ret;
 }
```

The Base64.NO_WRAP flag was lacking.

Comment: this saved me ,i had base64.default instead Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP

Comment: Amazing! Can someone explain why the line-ending matters in post but not get requests ?

Comment: @Koral: Your solution really helped alot for Authentication Challenge.

Comment: Thanks my guy,  ```Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP``` did the trick

Answer (score 3):

use simply this :

```
String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                        ("your_login" + ":" + "your_password").getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP); //Base64.NO_WRAP flag
                post.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);
```